# Simplest way to insert Javascript string into the html without a div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, templates

Using a templating engine I can always put variables into a text very simple like this:

```
Welcome {{ user.first_name }}
```

I now need to do this with a Javascript string. I know there are are js templating engines, but I just need to do it once, so I don't want to load a whole js templating library for this. I know I can do it with jQuery by creating a div in the desired place and then using the [.html method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to insert the string, but that also seems like a hassle for this simple thing.

In php, although it's ugly, you could do something like this:

```
Welcome <? echo user.first_name; ?>
```

Is there a comparable way to do this in Javascript? All tips are welcome!

Comment: You mean like this? `Welcome <script>user.first_name</script>`

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal - That doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/avtwbfh4/

Comment: see javascript is a client side language so you have to do something to get something. So in javascript one have to interact with document in a way to get the desired result.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a template engine running in JavaScript. E.g. Angular has built in templating. There are several more light weight engines available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is tagged as [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) you can use `:contains` pseudo-selector and replace it.

```
var first_name = "kramer65", placeholder = "{{ user.first_name }}"
$("html :contains('" + placeholder + "')").text(function(_, txt){
   return txt.replace(placeholder, first_name);
});
```

Just use `Welcome {{ user.first_name }}`
in html and since it has to be a child of any one of the container, the above code will work.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLbsjL32/1)

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal yeah. It's a bit overkill to use data-attributes'

Comment: Although its still way too much code to my taste, I guess it's the only way to go. Thanks!